# mikrotik joining two subnets

Tags: routing

I have two subnets which are geographically separated, connected by a wireless point to point link (5Mbps). Both networks are connected to internet through their own separate ILL WAN links which are configured on MikroTik routers. I want to connect the subnets through the routers. 
The scenario is :

**Site 1:**

192.168.10.0/24

Ether1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx ---- connected to Internet

Ether2 192.168.10.1/24    ---- connected to local LAN

**Site 2**

10.10.10.0/24

Ether1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx ---- connected to Internet

Ether2 10.10.10.1/24      ---- connected to local LAN

I want to connect the two LANs together so that there is a seamless traffic between the two.

NO FIREWALL rules on either routers.
Only source NAT masquerade on WAN links on both routers.
NO destination NAT

I have tried the below, which, obviously does not work.

**Site 1:**

192.168.10.0/24

Ether1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx ---- connected to Internet

Ether2 192.168.10.1/24    ---- connected to local LAN

Ether3 10.10.10.10/24     ---- P2P between Site 1 and 2

**Site 2**

10.10.10.0/24

Ether1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx ---- connected to Internet

Ether2 10.10.10.1/24      ---- connected to local LAN

Ether3 192.168.10.10/24  ---- P2P between Site 1 and 2

What am I missing? (Beside, looks like everything?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make the wireless link its own layer 3 subnet.  That will also help your link latency and saturation problems.

```
Site 1 ETH3 192.168.11.1/24 and 

Site 2, ETH3: 192.168.11.2/24.
```

Then add static routes between them:

Site 1

```
/ip route 
add dst-address=10.10.10.0/24 gateway=192.168.11.2
```

and Site 2:

```
/ip route 
add dst-address=192.168.10.0/24 gateway=192.168.11.1
```